# jQuery mobile remember history with back button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, html5-history

I created an application with jQuery mobile. There is a list of fields that will select a page or another as the sum of their values on different pages.

At the head I have put a navigation button back, but resets the values and results of the previous page.

I would like if the user pressing the back button returns the previous page maintained values and results if you want to modify any of the select.

Is there a way to remember history by pressing the back button?

Code back button:

```
<a href="#" class="ui-btn-left" data-rel="back" data-icon="back">Atrás</a>
```

Comment: are you using _Multi-Page Model_ (all pages in one file) or _Single Page Model_ (each page in a separate file)?

Comment: I'm using Multi-Page Model